# Mac Terminal batch file rename: flip string and digits

Tags: regex, macos, terminal, batch-processing

I read some threads about batch renames in Mac OS X Terminal and understood you can do something like this:

```
for file in *.pdf
do
    mv "$file" "<some magic regex>"
done
```

As you can guess, my issue is with the regex for this particular purpose:

**Old file**
Author-Year-Title.pdf

**New file**
Year-Author-Title.pdf

I did try some regex code but got stuck. I "just" want to flip Author and Year, but cannot figure out how. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do, or come quite close to doing, what you are asking for. The technique I am using is called `Bash Parameter Substitution` and it is documented and described very well [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html).

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.pdf
do
    echo DEBUG: Processing file $file
    f=${file%.*}           # strip extension from right end
    author=${f%%-*}        # shortest str at start that ends with dash
    title=${f##*-}         # shortest str at end that starts with dash
    authoryear=${f%-*}     # longest string at start that ends in dash
    year=${authoryear#*-}
    echo DEBUG: author:$author, year:$year, title:$title
    echo mv "$file" "$year-$author-$title.pdf"
done
```

Basically, I am extracting the `Author`, `Year` and `Title` into variables for you and then you can put them together in whatever order you like with whatever separators you like at the end and do the actual renaming. Note that the script actually does nothing until you remove the `echo` statement in front of the `mv` command so you can test it out and see what it would do.

Please practice on a COPY of your data in a spare, temporary directory.

**Sample Output**

```
DEBUG: Processing file Banks-2012-Something.pdf
DEBUG: author:Banks, year:2012, title:Something
mv Banks-2012-Something.pdf 2012-Banks-Something.pdf
DEBUG: Processing file Shakey-2013-SomethingElse.pdf
DEBUG: author:Shakey, year:2013, title:SomethingElse
mv Shakey-2013-SomethingElse.pdf 2013-Shakey-SomethingElse.pdf
```

If you like ugly `sed` commands you can do it more succinctly like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.pdf
do
    echo DEBUG: Processing file $file
    new=$(sed -E 's/(.*)-([0-9]{4})-(.*)\.*/\2-\1-\3.pdf/' <<< $file)
    echo $new
done
```

The `s/xxx/yyy/` means *substitute* or *replace* `xxx` with `yyy`. Anything inside parentheses must be captured as `capture groups` and then the first capture group becomes available as `\1` in the replacement and the second capture group becomes available as `\2` and so on. So it says... save anything up to the first dash as `\1`, exactly 4 digits between the next pair of dashes as `\2` and the other stuff as `\3`, and then it prints the captured groups out in a different order.

Comment: Thanks. I tested (obviously on copy of original data) and for most files it works as intended. For some it has problems finding the right cut for clear reasons, transforming e.g. `Fytagoridis-2013-Stimulation-induced side effe` into `2013-Stimulation-Fytagoridis-induced side effe`. (it has the extra dash)

I was wondering whether regex could contribute by specifically find the four-digit part of the filename (which is the year) and then flipping it with the string in front of the first dash. That would avoid this problem.

Comment: I was seduced by the dashes in your description! :-)  I have updated the second `sed` version as that is easier, so please try that again.

Comment: That works excellent! I just needed to remove `.pdf` (extension was saved from filename) and actually make the command work by changing `echo $new` into `mv "$file" "$new"`.

Thanks!